# Problem using Polar Irda device in Windows Server 2008

Tags: usb, windows-server-2008-r2, infrared

I'm attempting to use the Polar IrDA device with Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.
Although they dont make explicit drivers for it, I figured the Windows 7 x64 drivers would do.

http://www.polar.fi/en/support/downloads?product=&category=Software&documenttitle=Polar+IrDA+USB+Adapter+drivers&document=/gip/PKBStoGIP.nsf/web_cat/C225742500419A8AC2257458003D3F40

The device has a yellow warning icon in Device Manager.

```
Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)
```

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 1):

The broken driver from 2006 doesn't work on 2008r2.

But there is good news!

You can create a virtual machine on your 2008r2, install something old-fashioned on it, like XP, and then use that for your Polar training.

Then you'll have a problem that USB doesn't work in Hyper-V, but don't worry, even if Microsoft are too lazy to add proper features to their products, there are thankfully small third-party developers who have common sense.

Fabulatech has USB over Network solved in software, so you install the server on the 2008r2 machine and install the client on the Hyper-V XP, then share the "unknown" and "non-functional" Polar IrDA USB stick, and install the drivers on the XP - and it works!

A very roundabout way, but it's doable. I've been having the same problem and this is how I solved it.